# Make date tick marks align properly with plotted data points in ggvis

Tags: r, ggvis

Consider the following two plots made from this data frame:

```
temp = data.frame(x = seq(as.Date('2014-08-01'),as.Date('2014-08-30'),by=1), 
                  y = 1:30,
                 x2 = 1:30)
```

There is no problem using `ggvis` to plot vectors which are not dates:

```
temp %>%
    ggvis(~x2,~y) %>%
    layer_points()
```

[image: Points plotted correctly when x-axis is not a date]

However, when we try to use a date (in this case in the x-axis), we see that the tick marks no longer align with the plotted points.

```
temp %>%
    ggvis(~x,~y) %>%
    layer_points()
```

[image: Points not correctly aligned with respect to x-axis tick marks when x-axis is a date]

I am guessing this is some sort of bug, but in the interim, it seems like we can fix it by moving the x-axis ticks by a certain amount, but I do not know what this amount is, nor do I know how to move the tick marks.

Comment: I **strongly** suspect this is because it is interpreting a date as being midday (12:00) on that date, but the axis line is drawn at the start of that date (00:00). Try turning your dates into date-times (POSIXct) with a time-component of 00:00 and see if they hit the lines.

Comment: spot on Spacedman! post it as a solution!!! Just use: `temp = data.frame(x = seq(as.POSIXct('2014-08-01'),as.POSIXct('2014-08-30'),by=86400), y = 1:30, x2 = 1:30)
`

Comment: Actually I suspect you should upgrade `ggvis` since the dots line up nicely for me when I try your code (version 0.3.0.1). The reason I didn't know this when I commented was because that comment was written while I was waiting for ggvis and all its deps to install...

Comment: interesting, I am on the latest version: > `packageVersion("ggvis")
[1] ‘0.3.0.1’`

Comment: I have the version 0.3.0.1 on mac, and I had the same issue. I was playing with examples from the CRAN manual page 53-54, but `by=86400` generated right figures. This is something very good to know. Thanks a lot, Alex and Spacedman.

Comment: No issue on the same version of ggvis as Spacedman on W7.

Comment: interesting, I am on ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 1):

I've found that setting the time to 6:00 am for every observation in the data "fixes" the issue so that it aligns with the date tick marks. E.g. Date variable:

```
 [1] "12/27/2015 6:00:00" "12/29/2015 6:00:00" "12/26/2015 6:00:00" "12/30/2015 6:00:00"
 [5] "12/31/2015 6:00:00" "12/28/2015 6:00:00" "12/31/2015 6:00:00" "12/29/2015 6:00:00"
 [9] "12/30/2015 6:00:00" "12/31/2015 6:00:00" "12/26/2015 6:00:00" "12/28/2015 6:00:00"
```